# how to use angular ui-sref

Tags: angularjs, hyperlink, routes

I've got a table of order data with links to edit the order if they're not 'healthy'.

I'm not sure how to use the ui-sref to link back to my edit page, passing it the specific order Id. (I'm supposed to use ui-sref, right? Using href in a routed app is cheating is it not?)

This is the error I get:

> Could not resolve '#/editlisting/3' from state 'layout.orders'

Here's a snippet of code in my controller:

```
OrderService.getOrders().then (
  function success(response) {
    vm.Orders = response;
      angular.forEach(vm.Orders, function (order, k) {
        if (!order.listing.Completed) {
          order.Health.push({
            message: "Missing listing info.",
            link: "/editlisting/" + order.listing.Id
          });
        };
     )};
   }
});
```

All I am concerned about right now is

```
link: "/editlisting/" + order.listing.Id
```

A snippet of the html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="health in order.Health">
  <td>
    <div ng-repeat="health in order.Health">
      <a ui-sref="{{health.link}}">{{health.message}}</a>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

My route looks like this:

```
        $stateProvider
            .state('layout.editlisting', {
                url: '/editlisting/:id',
                templateUrl: 'Content/js/apps/store/views/edit_listing.html',
                controller: 'editListingController',
                controllerAs: 'listingVm',
                data: { pageTitle: 'Edit Listing' }
            })
```

(If I've mistyped a var or ref somewhere, don't worry too much about it. My problem is with the actual linking)

So, in a nutshell, this:

```
<a ui-sref="{{health.link}}">{{health.message}}</a>
```

gives me this:

> Could not resolve '#/editlisting/3' from state 'layout.orders'

Although this works fine:

```
<a href="{{health.link}}">{{health.message}}</a>
```

But that's bypassing the router completely, is it not?

Comment: `ui-sref` expects name of a state not a url. http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref

Answer (score 0):

Use the state instead of the URL and you can pass the id as below. I am using '3' as an example like your's:

```
<a ui-sref="layout.editlisting({id:3})">{{health.message}}</a>
```

Here is a [previous plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PYAp3C24dkJdE2LNOxGU) that I tweaked to add your layout.editlisting ui-sref... if you click to editlisting:

```
   <a ui-sref="layout.editlisting({id:3})">editlisting</a>
```

It will display the dummy template I created... just text:

```
    .state('layout', {
        url: '/layout',
        template: '<div ui-view/>',
        abstract: true
      })
  .state('layout.editlisting', {
    url: '/editlisting/:id',
    template: '<h1>edit listing id = {{ vm.id }}</h1>',
    data: {
      pageTitle: 'Edit Listing'
    },
    controller: function($stateParams) {
      var vm = this;
      console.log('Edit listing controller' + $stateParams.id);
      vm.id = $stateParams.id;
    },
    controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
```

In the controller, I retrieved the id using $stateParams.id (i.e. the one passed by the URL) and I display it `<h1>edit listing id = {{ vm.id }}</h1>`